# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' после компиляц

Tags: python, pillow

После компиляции программы, она перестаёт запускаться, выдавая ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом, при запуске программы в среде разработки всё работает идеально. Только после компиляции. Пробовал и переустановить пакет, перерыл весь Гугл но ничего не помогло.
**Заранее спасибо за помощь**

Comment: Компиляция это что?

Comment: Вы чем компилируете в ЕХЕ? Для pyinstaller --hiddenimport есть, а вообще, если делать через venv, и туда всё поставить, то собирается просто pyinstaller -w -F --noconsole file.py

Comment: Компилирую командой pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile main.py в терминале

Comment: --hiddenimport не помог, вопрос всё ещё актуален

Answer (score 0):

Я программист-любитель на python и столкнулся с той же проблемой (таже ошибка после запуска .exe файла, хотя в среде разработки все работало отлично), но нашел вариант ее решения: Есть вероятность что модуль Pil не установлен правильно. Чтобы в этом убедиться необходимо открыть командную строку Windows (желательно от администратора) и ввести запрос pip3 show Pillow. Если он установлен то появится информация о модуле.
Если нет, то необходимо ввести команду (в случае установленного python версии 3 и выше) python3 -m pip show Pillow для его инсталляции. Полезные ссылки:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-pil
https://morioh.com/p/f7009f71b59f